# Jackson + restlet + tomcat - Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonConverter

Tags: java, json, tomcat, serialization, jackson

I'm having issues using jackson with restlet in tomcat environment.
As you can read from the [restlet site](http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.2/extensions/jackson), they assures that the jackson extension

> provides a plugin for the ConverterService which will automatically serialize and deserialize your Java objets returned by annotated methods in ServerResource subclasses.

and that

> our Customer and Address classes are just regular serializablecbeans, with no special parent classes and no special annotations.

So, trying to emulate the example, I've written a simple test example.
This is the server resource

```
public class TestUri extends ServerResource
{
    @Get("json")
    public User retrieve()
    {
        User u = new User("mail", "password", "nick", new Date());
        u.setId(1);
        return u;
    }
}
```

and this is the client resource

```
    private static void testJacksonFromRestlet()
    {
        ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("<restlet-uri>");
        User u = cr.get(User.class);
    }
```

I tried also to use curl if this matter

```
curl -i -X get -H "Content-Type: application/json" <url>
```

but (as expected, I have to say) when I try to contact the restlet at the specified address, an exception was thrown.

```
Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonConverter

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: APPLICATION_YAML
    at org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonConverter.<clinit>(JacksonConverter.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelper(Engine.java:897)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:931)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.registerHelpers(Engine.java:971)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.discoverConverters(Engine.java:680)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:508)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:382)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.register(Engine.java:368)
    at org.restlet.engine.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:252)
    at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:334)
    at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:393)
    at org.restlet.data.Method.<init>(Method.java:358)
    at org.restlet.data.Method.<clinit>(Method.java:57)
    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.<init>(ClientResource.java:405)
```

These are the packages I have deployed on the server
[image: Deployed packages]

I don't know how to proceed. To me, it seems that one or more of the followings are true

- I'm missing something on the library side. However, I don't know what yaml stands for and I don't want to use it, only the simple json serializer/deserializer
- I'm missing something on the `web.xml` file (which is very simple at the moment, containing only the redirect application). However, I don't know how to configure it to correctly use jackson
- I'm missing something in the code.

---

### EDIT 1

My problem seems to be related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815193/why-is-restlet-unable-to-register-the-json-converter) SO question and also with [this](http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4447&dsMessageId=2934357).
However, after many tries, I wasn't able to solve it.

Among the others, I've also tried to export the META-INF/services folder from org.restlet.ext.jackson on META-INF/services , but I don't know if it make sense at all, given that the problem is still here.

I tried also to invoke `Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters().add(new JacksonConverter());` from my `Application`, but it results in `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonConverter`.

So, I'm quite stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a step backwards, like -
Instead of directly converting the incoming data to USER class, why dont you store it as a JSON Object and then use an ObjectMapper from Jackson to get the User instance ?

With this you can know the right stage at which the error is thrown. I am using Jackson for something very similar to what you are using and I have no issues till now.

Once you save the outup into a JSON object, you can use the readValue method of the ObjectMapper class

** Sample Code**

In my case, the response is an array of JSONObjects, so here is how it works in this case.

```
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response); 
      for (int i=0; i< array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
            POJOClass = mapper.readValue(obj.toString(),POJO.class);
            dataArr.add(data);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :)
Could you provide example code?

Comment: Do you mean send only a `JSONObject` from the restlet and then use an `ObjectMapper` on the client?If it's so, I think that it's not possible: jackson is the only one to support circular dependencies into pojo objects; with other jsons (`gson` or `java-json`) I always have a stack overflow exception.
Also, if it matters, even if I remove the jackson's packages from the deployment and the `ObjectManager` from the restlet class, I'm continuing to have the exception `INFO: Unable to register the helper org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonConverter
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: APPLICATION_YAML`

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared deleting the `org.restlet.ext.jackson.jar` from the deployed libraries. I'm trying to investigate more on the problem and I'll update the question in the next few hours.
Also, it seems that the problem appeared only on the latest releases; adding the `org.restlet.ext.jackson-2.0.0.jar` doesn't throw any kind of exception.

Though, I'm still not able to directly convert POJO to JSON using this extension.